# Validate url parameters with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, validation, url, preg-match

Valid example

```
12[red,green],13[xs,xl,xxl,some other text with chars like _&-@#%]
number[anythingBut ()[]{},anythingBut ()[]{}](,number[anythingBut ()[]{},anythingBut ()[]{}]) or nothing


Full match 12[red,green]
Group 1 12
Group 2 red,green


Full match 13[xs,xl,xxl,some other text with chars like _&-@#%]
Group 1 13
Group 2 xs,xl,xxl,some other text with chars like _&-@#%
```

Not valid example

```
13[xs,xl,xxl 9974-?ds12[dfgd,dfgd]]
```

What I tried is this: `(\d+(?=\[))\[([^\(\[\{\}\]\)]+)\]`, [regex101 link with what I tried](https://regex101.com/r/Gm4Ccy/2), but this also matches wrong input like given in the example.

Comment: What would you expect for `13[xs,xl,xxl 9974-?ds12[dfgd,dfgd]],12[red,green]`?

Comment: No match if that's posibble or a match for the one with correct syntax `12[red,green]`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to validate the input, you can add some anchors:

```
^(?:\d+\[[^\(\[\{\}\]\)]+\](?:,|$))+$
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ABDEfX/1)

If you also need to get all the matching parts, you can use another regex. Using only one will not work well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$in = '12[red,green],13[xs,xl,xxl,some other text with chars like _&-@#%],13[xs,xl,xxl 9974-?ds12[dfgd,dfgd]]';
preg_match_all('/(\d+)\[([^][{}()]+)(?=\](?:,|$))/', $in, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12[red,green
            [1] => 13[xs,xl,xxl,some other text with chars like _&-@#%
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => red,green
            [1] => xs,xl,xxl,some other text with chars like _&-@#%
        )

)
```

**Explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
  (\d+)         : group 1, 1 or more digits
  \[            : open square bracket
  (             : start group 2
    [^][{}()]+  : 1 or more any character that is not open or close parenthesis, brackets or square brackets
  )             : end group 2
  (?=           : positive lookahead, make sure we have after
    \]          : a close square bracket
    (?:,|$)     : non capture group, a comma or end of string
  )             : end group 2
/               : regex delimiter
```